# Including a ModelForm in admin.py from forms.py

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I want to add a custom field to admin.py **"extra_field"** which is defined in YourModelForm class in **forms.py**
**forms.py**

```
***class YourModelForm(forms.ModelForm):***

extra_field = forms.CharField()

def save(self, commit=True):
    extra_field = self.cleaned_data.get('extra_field', None)
    # ...do something with extra_field here...
    return super(YourModelForm, self).save(commit=commit)

class Meta:
    model = movie
    fields = '__all__'
```

**admin.py**

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
    from __future__ import unicode_literals

    from django.contrib import admin

    from . models import movie, genre

    from . import forms

    class movieAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

        form = YourModelForm

        list_display=('movie_name', 'movie_rating','Date','count',)
        search_fields=('movie_name',)
        filter_horizontal=('movie_genres',)
        list_filter=('Date',)
        date_hierarchy='Date'
        ordering=('-movie_name',)
        fields=('movie_name','movie_rating','movie_genres', 'extra_field',)



    class genreAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
         list_display=('genre_name',)


    admin.site.register(movie, movieAdmin)
    admin.site.register(genre, genreAdmin)
```

NameError: name 'YourModelForm' is not defined

Comment: Well, you haven't imported it.

Comment: @DanielRoseman unable to do that. Can you help? how to import?

Comment: @Metaphox no he doesn't.

Comment: @DanielRoseman ah, sorry. just realized what it is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've imported the `forms` module as a whole, so you need to use that qualified name:

```
form = forms.YourModelForm
```

(Note, this is standard Python import semantics, and nothing to do with Django specifically.)

Comment: showing error-->:: form = forms.YourModelForm
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'YourModelForm'

Comment: You need to show your directory structure. Is YourModelForm defined in the forms.py in the same directory as this admin file and the movie and genre models?

Comment: yes, admin.py, models.py, forms.py are all inside admin123(app) directory

Comment: adding this to admin.py--> from admin123.forms import YourModelForm And adding this to forms.py-->from django import forms,,,
from . models import movie, genre... resolved the problem. Thanks @Daniel Roseman